# display text on hovering mouse over a button in gwt

Tags: button, gwt

I am using gwt 2.4. And I am not using uibinder. 
I have a button which has a background image. when I place mouse on this button it should display a text saying "submit" . The kind of text which says what the button does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button` is a `UIObject` and so you can use [setTitle](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)) method on a `Button` to set the tooltip.

Or if you want to do something else on mouse over. Just make use of the mouse handlers.

Read [Button documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html) for more details.